# Change column name based on reference table

Tags: sql

My company database has column names like this: [VHCONO],[VHFACI],[VHPRNO],[VHMFNO],[VHITNO].  There is a reference table that identifies these colums.

I would like to write a query and have the field names changed based on this reference table.  The ref table is named CFIFFD

Here is my query now:

```
SELECT VHCONO, VHFACI, VHPRNO, VHMFNO, VHITNO, VHVANO 
  FROM MWOHED
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want such an unpivoting

```
select VHFLDI, VHFTXT
  from
     ( Select max(VHCONO) As VHCONO,
              max(VHFACI) As VHFACI,
              max(VHPRNO) As VHPRNO,
              max(VHMFNO) As VHMFNO,
              max(VHITNO) As VHITNO,
              max(VHVANO) As VHVANO
         From MWOHED ) p
unpivot  
   (VHFTXT for VHFLDI in
    ([VHCONO], [VHFACI], [VHPRNO], [VHMFNO], [VHITNO], [VHVANO])
) unpvt;

VHFLDI  VHFTXT
------  ----------------
VHCONO  Company
VHFACI  Facility
VHPRNO  Product
VHMFNO  Man.Order Number
VHITNO  item number
VHVANO  product variant
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/UENU54032)</kbd>

Comment: Barbaros, the WHFTXT field is in a different table: CFIFFD

Comment: @user3642767 please elaborate then (as a text for sample input/output would be better )

Comment: can't figure how to post a pic or excel snippet here

Comment: SELECT [VHCONO],[VHFACI],[VHPRNO],[VHMFNO],[VHITNO] FROM MWOHED

Comment: SELECT WHFILE, WHFLDI,WHFTXT FROM CFIFFD WHERE WHFILE='MWOHED'